# Bayeux sessions are missing in websphere cluster

Tags: jms, websphere, websphere-8, bayeux

I have a Bayeux implementation as [specified by IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.webmsg.help/docs/ApplicationPublishing.html). In a stand-alone environment it works fine, but when we put it into production (clusterized), sessions are getting lost after a while. We are using SIBUS as the bus implementation and the default messaging provider. In SIBUS we are using a database based data store. Our web server is WebSEAL.

We are sure this is not a replication issue since:

1. Sticky sessions are enabled
2. After start-up, every participant is able to see each other, which means that it doesn't matter where you signed-in, session is being replicated by both servers.

The main symptom is that after a few minutes of working OK, the long-polled request hangs until a new request originated at the client side happens. There are no exceptions shown anywhere.

I still cannot tell if my problem is with the SIBUS configuration, or if it would have something to do with the WebSEAL configuration.

Any help will be really appreciated. IBM documentation is not the best and we have been testing every piece of advice found in several documents with no luck.

**EDIT :**
After some testing, I have found that the behavior happens also on non-clusterized environments. I'm also seeing an exception with the code CWPSB1314W, which gives me [nothing](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.webmsg.resources.Messages.html).

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but you've gone through the difference between your stand-alone environment and the non-clustered one where it fails?

Comment: After several days of trying to fix this issue on code and/or Websphere cluster configuration we realized that the origin of the problem was not related to clusterization itself, but to load balancing.

I cannot exactly tell what was happening on the load balancers, but when going through those was the origin of the problem. All I can tell you is that Cisco confirmed it was a known issue, nevertheless I couldn't keep on diagnosing since from then on it was the network people who solved that problem.